# Child div to extend and break out of parent on the right side only

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container that sits in the middle of the screen. and i need the child div to align as relative and normal on the left side but the right side of the div to break out and align itself with the right side of the screen.

Example.

[image]

i've tried using the full-width technique as commonly used:

```
.child {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50vw;
  right: 50%;
}
```

and then amending it so that it doesn't go out on the left side. but this causes the right side to extend past the right side of the viewport.

this is the basic structure below.

```css
body {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.color__white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.border__black {
  border: 1px solid #454545;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 72rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:80vw;
  padding:15px;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent color__white">
  <div class="child border__black">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please explain more in detail.

Comment: @rarblack i've added an image to help everyone understand what i require.

Comment: is your `parent` width always `80vw` ? or a fixed width ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use a `calc` to calculate the width of the overhang (for screen sizes over 1440px - where your rem is smaller than your 80vw):

```css
body {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.color__white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.border__black {
  border: 1px solid #454545;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 72rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80vw;
  padding: 15px;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90vw;            /* this is just 90vw as the width of parent is 80vw, so extending bit to edge is the remaining 20vw / 2 */
}

@media screen and (min-width:1440px) {
  .child {
    width: calc(72rem + ((100vw - 72rem) / 2));
    /* this is the original 72rem width of the parent plus the size of the viewport minus the parent width divided by 2 - the extending bit between the window and parent */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent color__white">
  <div class="child border__black">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using margin:

```css
body {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.color__white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.border__black {
  border: 1px solid #454545;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 72rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80vw;
  padding: 15px;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right:-10vw; /*(100vw - 80vw)/2*/
}

@media screen and (min-width:1440px) {
  .child {
    margin-right:calc((72rem - 100vw)/2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent color__white">
  <div class="child border__black">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin:0px;
}

.color__white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.border__black {
  border: 1px solid #454545;
}

.container{
  position:relative;
  padding:0 10%;
  margin-bottom:5%;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top:5%;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  position:relative;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  margin-left:5%;
  width: 90%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class="parent color__white">
  <div class="child border__black">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you have misunderstood the requirement of the question. I've added an image to help everyone understand.